# Logger for Sails JS?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I know `sails.log("some text")` replaces `console.log` in SailsJS, but - How do I log things like `info`, `warn` and just normal text instead of `error` in Sails 0.10x?

Answer (score 5):

This information can all be found here: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Logging

Essentially you can do `sails.log()`, `sails.warn()`, `sails.error`, etc. and then specify which level of logs you want to see via the `config/log.js` file.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sails.log['logLevel']` like `sails.log.warn` or `sails.log.error`

Logs by order or precedence:

```
sails.log.error()
sails.log.warn()
sails.log.debug()
sails.log.info()
sails.log.verbose()
sails.log.silly()
```

by default sails log level config is `sails.config.log.level = 'info'` then verbose and silly dont are displayed

More infos: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Logging